# Game Center sign in dialogue not appearing

Tags: ios, game-center

I'm using Apples Game Center to sign the players in at the start of the game, the problem is I've just hit cancel (to test the eventually) and now the dialogue box won't appear anymore, it just keeps going straight through to disabled.

Here's the function I'm using.

```
-(void) setup
{
    gameCenterAuthenticationComplete = NO;

    if (!isGameCenterAPIAvailable()) {
        // Game Center is not available.
        NSLog(@"Game Center is not available.");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Game Center is available.");

        __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self; // removes retain cycle error

        GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer =  [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer]; // localPlayer is the public GKLocalPlayer

        __weak GKLocalPlayer *weakPlayer = localPlayer; // removes retain cycle error

        weakPlayer.authenticateHandler = ^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error)
        {
            if (viewController != nil)
            {
                NSLog(@"Try to show ViewController");
                [weakSelf showAuthenticationDialogWhenReasonable:viewController];
            }
            else if (weakPlayer.isAuthenticated)
            {
                NSLog(@"authenticate player");
                [weakSelf authenticatedPlayer:weakPlayer];
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"disable");
                [weakSelf disableGameCenter];
            }
        };
    }

}

-(void)disableGameCenter
{

}
```

As you can see disableGameCenter doesn't actually do anything anyway.

Why is it going to disable every time I now run it? (working with the simulator) and how can I get it out of that so the the dialogue appears again? Do I have to manually force the dialogue to appear again somehow?

Comment: Having the same problem as well. For first time run, it shows the login view. After I logout and run the app again, it just shows "GameCenter Unavailable" message alert.

Comment: Bit of advice is if something is not working with Game Center give it 6-8 hours and come back and try again, sometimes it just doesn't work as it should, although there is the issue that if you cancel login 3 times I Think it is, it locks you out, look on here for solutions to that.

Comment: I've faced the same issue on iOS 8 iphone 5C. Do you have any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue under OSX, after you "cancel" the Gamecenter dialog a few times, it stops appearing.

To get it back, run "Game Center", Login and Logout - and then run your game again and the dialogbox will appear again ( it works at least a few times, until you 'cancel' too often ).